# How to push and pop view controllers in UISplitViewController in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

From Apple's Documentation,

> When designing your split view interface, it is best to install
>   primary and secondary view controllers that do not change. A common
>   technique is to install navigation controllers in both positions and
>   then push and pop new content as needed.

My app has a `UISplitViewController` as a root view controller. As per documentation, I created two dummy navigation controllers(say primaryNC & secondaryNC) and placed them as primary & secondary view controllers in `UISplitViewController` using the `setViewControllers:` method.

My primary controller is a tab bar controller, and the secondary controller is normal UIViewController.

I can not find how to push/pop view controllers into primary/secondary navigation controllers. Redirecting to any example code would be helpful.

P.S: I am doing this programmatically not using nib/xib. I am using objective c.

Comment: What problem are you having? Do you know how to push and pop view controllers in a navigation controller?

Comment: I knew how to push/pop viewcontrollers in navigation stack using pushViewController: and popViewControllerAnimated:. But I'm confused about UISplitViewController's delegate methods. Should I assign my primary/secondary view controllers via split view's delegate methods? or can I just push the needed controllers using navigation stack?

Comment: A sample working code can give more clear picture on this. But I can not see any objective c code that do not use any storyboards in web. :(